# Google sheets formula to calculate hours after a specific time and day

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am new to google sheets, but I have this very simple and basic tracking system for my work schedule. I wish to make a formula so it automatically finds the number of hours on nights and weekends column, after a specific time.

So ex. night hours between 9 pm-11 pm Monday - Friday and weekend hours between 2 pm-8 pm on Saturday and Sunday.

[image]

[image]

Comment: can your share your spreadsheet to work with your locale?

Comment: thx, I will take a copy to work on one month first

Comment: `night hours between 9 pm-11 pm Monday - Friday` ... question : what happens after 11pm?

Comment: my line of work ends at 11pm, so nothing happens after that

Comment: but on Thursday 23. December I see 23:30!

Comment: oh yes, if it happens the night hours just extends, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you get the expected hours (sorry for the layout a bit different!)
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YuY_8XgMUsPtBPJlBgxDFgz8JKB3lCmn2e6vVEutvBY/edit?usp=sharing

test if we `=WEEKDAY(A4,2)>5`

day on monday-friday `=if(D4,, max(0,min(21/24,C4)-B4))`

night on monday-friday `=if(D4, ,max(0,C4-max(21/24,B4)))`

Comment: Thank you very much! I do not need the day times, but it is what i was looking for! So to just try and understand a bit myself. What would I need to change if i wanted to change the times ex. 2pm-8pm to 2pm-10pm?

Comment: I didn't take account of 8pms since you tell me that it could be extra hours!

Comment: okay, so it just takes the 2pm in account and extends til midnight? It is what i wanted, so just trying to understand the formula, dont seem to understand the '21/24' and '14/24' parts, the rest seems fair

Comment: oh! 21 because of 9pm and 14 because of 2pm?

Comment: yes,(12+9)/24 = 9pm and (12+2)/24 = 2pm!